# Magento 2 Setup:Upgrade giving error of Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing, setup-upgrade

I have moved my website files and DB from one server to another.

Now, When I am running setup:upgrade command. I am getting below error:

Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
> constraint, query was: ALTER TABLE `quote_item` MODIFY COLUMN
> `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Item Id",
> ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`), ADD CONSTRAINT
> `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE
> CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN
> KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, ADD
> INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID` (`parent_item_id`), ADD INDEX
> `QUOTE_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`), ADD INDEX
> `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID` (`quote_id`), ADD INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID`
> (`store_id`)

---

Please help to get rid of this error.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this error. if Yes, Please Share the Solution. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find this solution ? i am also getting this.

Comment: @sumeetbajaj: Did you find this solution? I am also getting this.

Comment: @VishalThakur: Did you find this solution? I am also getting this.

Comment: @BalwantSingh no bro.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this query:

```
Select item_id from quote_item where parent_item_id is not null and parent_item_id in (select item_id from quote_item)
```

After that, the result will be updated and you need to fix it to **parent_item_id = null**.

Leave a comment if it works!

Comment: Not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error from last five days when I tried to upload on godaddy server from localhost. It is working fine at localhost but shown following error on server:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint, query was: ALTER TABLE `quote_item` MODIFY COLUMN `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Item ID", ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`), ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE SET NULL, ADD INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID` (`parent_item_id`), ADD INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`), ADD INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID` (`quote_id`), ADD INDEX `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID` (`store_id`)

Kindly help

Comment: Did you find this solution? I am also getting this.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue i would suggest you to run below commands in sequence :

```
rm -rf generated; \
php bin/magento indexer:reindex; \
php bin/magento setup:upgrade; \
php bin/magento setup:di:compile; \
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy; -f \
php bin/magento cache:clean; \
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

then check also after running if its still not resolved then i would suggest to enabled developer mode for your setup and then run the same bunch of commands in sequence and then check !

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding foreign key with the `catalog_product_entity` table or any other Magento2 core table then you need to match the column data type and other information with the table you are creating for your module. They both should match.